# sencha2 integration with phonegap for android build fail

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, sencha-touch

I am integrating sencha touch2 with phonegap for android.I have successfull created a sample app in my localhost.Now i am trying to integrate it with phonegap for android following this tutorial

http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/

**What i have done so far**

1. created new sencha application(AndroidSencha)
2. Created a new folder name android in side AndroidSencha.
3. Created a project there in android using eclipse.
4. changed the logger: 'no' to 'false' in app.json.
5. copy cordova-2.1.0.js to root folder to sencha(i am using phonegap2.1.0 on windows)
6. added
   "js": [
   {
       "path": "cordova-2.1.0.js"
   },
   to app.json

When i am trying "sencha app build testing -d android/assets/www " on command prompt.I am getting "build fail" message

I cant go ahead from here ..

Pls help..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version of Sencha Touch (2.1) with Sencha Cmd.